# Is possible upgrade RAM for a MBP 13-inch, Early 2011?

Tags: macos, hardware, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

My *uncle* has the following MacBook Pro, it according with *About This Mac*

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)
- Processor 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- Graphics Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

Furthermore, in the back of the laptop appears `Model No:A1278`

I want to know if is possible upgrade to 16 or even with 32 GB of RAM - if yes, what are the correct specs of each memory? It indicate to my uncle to buy the correct pair through Amazon.